# How can I move the private methods of a big class out of a single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rather big class with much functionality, made out of:

- 3 public methods
- 20+ private methods
- zero state (no attributes)

What is the best option to split my class into multiple files, while keeping the 3 public methods into the initial file, and not making the private implementations accesible to the entire application?

Comment: the entire application will always have access, this is ruby.

But you can do it the other way around, defining a public module with your public API, which is itself included in a private implementation which you get through a getter / factory / whatever

Comment: The public methods probably call the private methods. Moving the latter into a separate file will make your code harder to understand. A reader will have to skip between both files. I'd just put the public methods on top and the private methods below the `private` keyword.

Comment: Ruby classes are open. Just **literally split** the implementation into several files.

Comment: @Stefan I could not disagree more. Implementation details, buried into private methods, should not be of any interest for the reader. If you expect anybody to need to understand what’s there in private methods, the implementation is flawed.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin implementation details should not be of interest, regardless of whether it's a private or public method. But if I have to dig into the implementation for some reason, I usually want / need all the details.

Comment: @Stefan than opening two files in the editor panes side by side would make your life even easier :)

Comment: what are you trying to achive here? moving private methods somewhere sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @phoet the main file is just getting to big, so I hoping of a way to make the code more readable

Comment: put the methods where they are used! moving stuff to another file decreases readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could reopen the class and just define private methods.

Alternatively, you could define a module and include that in your class:

```
module FooPrivate
  private

  def greet
    'hello'
  end
end

class Foo
  include FooPrivate

  def hello
    greet
  end
end
```

The above in action:

```
irb> Foo.new.greet
NoMethodError (private method `greet' called for #<Foo:0x00007f83ba04bd58>)
irb> Foo.new.hello
=> "hello"
```